# SQLite Query to Get Column Data

Tags: android, sqlite

Using following query to get column data:

```
public String getR(String str) {

    String strR = "SELECT col_no FROM tracking where col_id = '"+str+"' ORDER BY col_no DESC LIMIT 1";

    return strR;
}
```

In *Activity*, I am trying to **read** returned `strR` :

```
    String string = mydb.getR("1400");
    Toast.makeText(SyncAll.this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But in **Toast**, I am `getting` my *Select query* itself instead of `Record`, like this:

```
SELECT col_no FROM tracking where col_id = '1400' ORDER BY col_no DESC LIMIT 1
```

***May I know ! Where I am doing mistake ?***

Comment: Dude, use `SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(strR, null);` to execute query on DB then extract data from Cursor

Comment: please don't downvote this, I tried and posted my code too... please respect that

Comment: I never down-vote this type of posts. and for problem see following tut [Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) `getAllContacts()` method

Comment: thanks I got the solution, your trick worked for me... @ρяσѕρєяK Ticked your comment as useful

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same way suggested by prosper k above, and finally got the solution:

```
public String getR(String str) {

    String strR = "SELECT col_no FROM tracking where col_id = '"+str+"' ORDER BY col_no DESC LIMIT 1";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(strR, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        strR = cursor.getString(0);

    return strR;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function getR, which is returning the string value strR.

I'm assuming that mydb is an extended object from class SQLiteOpenHelper, and that you have followed the documentation here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html then you'll have to execute the query like:

```
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        synchronized(this) {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                col_no = cursor.getInt(0);
            }

        }
    } finally {
        if (null != cursor)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return col_no;
```